# System Modal Transition Animation Settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I feel like this information is out there somewhere, but my Google searches came up with too much unrelated info to track down exactly what I was looking for. Basically I'd like to perform a `UIView` animation that matches the system's default modal view controller display animation (`UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`). I'm going to be doing this animation on a container view so I can make it partially transparent. No matter what settings I use I can't seem to match that transition though, and it looks a bit weird.

Here's my question: Does anyone know the animation settings used to match the system's default modal transition? Duration, curve, etc. It seems like an EaseOut curve, but that doesn't seem to match either.